# Upload Image from Gallery to FTP No such file or directory

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an image selected from the gallery to my ftp server.

My code:

```
public void imageButton() {
        chooseImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                System.out.println("GETTING HERE");
                startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this, "Image selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri selected = data.getData();
            new uploadFTP().execute(selected.getPath());
        }
    }

    class uploadFTP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try {

                ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("address"));
                ftpClient.login("hostname", "passowrd");
                ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("Connected to FTP");
                }
                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String testName = "/public_html/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "test";
                File file = new File(Arrays.deepToString(strings));
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ftpClient.storeFile(testName,fis);
                System.out.println("Successful");




            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
I/System.out: Connected to FTP
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [/external/images/media/217] (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
        at com.example.ufaza.androidsqlitesearch.AddProduct$uploadFTP.doInBackground(AddProduct.java:147)
        at com.example.ufaza.androidsqlitesearch.AddProduct$uploadFTP.doInBackground(AddProduct.java:130)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

So, I know my FTP connection works as I have another class which uploads text file to my ftp correctly, but now I am trying to upload an image from the gallery and I am getting an error that there is no such file or directory for the image, so I am assuming the path is wrong or something? I am unsure on how I am doing it wrong and require some advice.

Answer (score 0):

A `Uri` is not a file.

*If* the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, *then* it represents a file on the filesystem that, in theory, your app should be able to access. Use `getPath()` to get the filesystem path.

If the scheme is anything else, it does not necessarily represent a file on the filesystem that your app can access. For example, if the scheme is `http` or `https`, the `Uri` represents something that would be downloaded from a Web server.

If the scheme is `content`, then it is backed by a `ContentProvider`. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: So I should do:: `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); and then should I then just do `ftpClient.storeFile(testName,inputStream)` ? I did this and it says No Content provider am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: @JameshGong: I have no idea if `ftpClient.storeFile()` supports an `InputStream`. FTP is horribly insecure; nobody should be using it.